# Discuss the complexity of various python methods to obtain N largest elements from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I know of two approaches to it. The first one: documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```
heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)
```

and the second traditional approach of using sorted

```
sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:K]
```

The documentation mentions that these two are equivalent. However, I just wanted to know if the complexity of both are the same or if the first approach was implemented with lesser time complexity.

I remember from my algorithms course that obtaining top K elements from a list can be done in lesser order of operations compared to sorting the entire list and then going with picking the top K.
Correct me if I am wrong

**Edit:** What standard python libs can perform this task in O(N) operations or what's the best complexity we can get from python?

Comment: The documentation says "equivalent" not identical so I would guess the time complexity is different for both. See [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not a great mathematician*, but I guess it should depend mostly on two things:

1. relation between K and length of an iterable
2. relation between amount of python and cpython code executed.

Generally you're right, and quick tests show the difference in numbers:

```
>>> timeit(stmt='sorted(i)[-100:]', setup='from random import seed,random;seed(666);i=[random() for _ in range(10000)]', number=1000)
2.086820379132405
>>> timeit(stmt='heapq.nlargest(n, i)', setup='from random import seed,random;import heapq;seed(666);n=100;i=[random() for _ in range(10000)]', number=1000)
0.5397011679597199
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more fast algorithm [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) that does not perform full sorting - just makes partition, and has average complexity about `O(N)`.

Thanks to @Violet Red comment:  [numpy.partition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html)

Complexity of heap approach is `O(NlogK)`, of sort approach is `O(NlogN)`.

C++ STL contains method `partial_sort` that might execute faster that full sorting.

Comment: Can you think of any python built-in library method that uses QuickSelect algorithm in accomplishing this task?

Comment: I don't know, but I see a lot of implementations in Google search that don't mention any standard methods.

Comment: There are  some partitioning functions in numpy, that probably can be fast and usable.

Answer (score 0):

Finding top K elements, can be done with complexities less than O(N * logN) with

- heap based solution in O(N * logK)
- [Median of Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) solution in O(N)